# inverse discrete fourier transform with plain python

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, python, ifft

I am trying to calculate inverse discrete fourier transform for an array of signals.

I am using the following formula:

$$ x[n] = \tfrac1N \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] \, e^{j 2 \pi k n/N} $$

And my python code looks as follow.

```
def IFT(array):
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=float)
    # array length
    N = array.shape[0]
    # new array of lenght N [0, N-1]
    n = np.arange(N)
    k = n.reshape((N, 1))
    # Calculate the exponential of all elements in the input array.
    M = np.exp(2j * np.pi * k * n / N)
    return 1 / N * np.dot(M, array)

y = 2*np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t+0.2) + 3*np.cos(2*np.pi*f2*t+0.3) + noise*5
IFT(sc.fft(y))

array([ 3.42732136e+00+0.00000000e+00j,  4.81582993e+00-4.10374772e-16j,
    5.86456023e+00+3.88824673e-16j,  4.07942919e+00-1.48609552e-15j,
    5.25077594e+00+6.70968395e-16j,  6.45823471e+00-1.22977116e-15j,
...
sc.ifft(sc.fft(y))

array([ 3.42732136-8.59756710e-16j,  5.34401724+4.97379915e-17j,
    5.46939384-9.87654403e-16j,  3.31504852-4.17443857e-16j,
    6.52888175+6.39488462e-16j,  6.90804001-3.10862447e-16j,
...
```

but if I compare array returned from `Scipy.ifft` with the one returned from my own function `IFT`, I get completely different array. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you confusing `n` and `N`?

Comment: You are right, but still there is something wrong

Comment: I tested your function's body code and it works fine ? (checked with Matlab's ifft)... May be you are mis-using *scipy.ifft* ?

Comment: Really? I added my comparison with Scipy, results are slightly different

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think it'd be good to include your result vs the result given by the mentioned library.

[Here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/fftpack/basic.py#L291-L371) is the code of `scipy`'s `ifft`. In [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.ifft.html) it states that the function returns a

> complex array contains y(0), y(1),..., y(n-1) where
>
> `y(j) = (x * exp(2*pi*sqrt(-1)*j*np.arange(n)/n)).mean()`.

I suspect that you're trying to write the imaginary unit as $j$, and I'm not sure that works fine... try replacing it with `sqrt(-1)`.

PS: Just noticed, but you want to compute idft on an array of signals? Or an array which represents a signal?

Comment: I added the results

Answer (score 1):

Removing the 2nd term -> `array = np.asarray(array, dtype=float)` should work